# Forward declaration and global namespace declaration

Tags: c++, namespaces, include, forward-declaration

I have difficulties to setup a structure with 3 classes. I'm not sure about includes / forward declaration.

The code below compiles until I add the namespace and enum in inclino.h. I receive "inclino has not been declared" from InclinoMeasure.h

Inclino.h

```cpp
// Inclino.h
#include "InclinoMeasure.h"
#include "InclinoReading.h"

namespace inclino {
enum a{a1, a2}
}

class Inclino
{
    list<InclinoMeasure*> m_measures;

    void f(inclino::a a);
}
```

InclinoMeasure.h

```
// InclinoMeasure.h
#include "InclinoReading.h"

class Inclino;

class InclinoMeasure
{
    Inclino *m_inclino;
    list<InclinoReading*> m_readings;

    void f(inclino::a a);
}
```

InclinoReading.h

```
// InclinoReading.h

class Inclino;
class InclinoMeasure;

class InclinoReading
{
    InclinoMeasure *m_inclino;

    void f(inclino::a a);
}
```

Does the structure is correct ? How can I access the enum in others class ?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :** I fixed the namespace issue by putting it in a new file including by the 3 classes. But seems I misused the include / forward declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> I receive "inclino has not been declared" from InclinoMeasure.h

This is because the namespace `inclino` and enum `a` are currently defined in `Inclino.h`, but `InclinoMeasure.h` does not include `Inclino.h` (and should not, given the current relationship between the headers, since that would introduce a circular dependency). The forward declaration of `class Inclino` is irrelevant to the namespace and enum.

To solve this problem, you can move the definition of the namespace and enum to `InclinoReading.h`.

This will make it available in all three headers where it is used, since both `Inclino.h` and `InclinoMeasure.h` include `InclinoReading.h`.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the enum but I have "Invalid use of incomplete type 'class Inclino'" from InclinoMeasure.cpp (when I call an Inclino method). My problem is more about forward declaration I think.

Comment: Have you included `Inclino.h` in `InclinoMeasure.cpp`? If not, this could cause `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Inclino'`. Also, you should make sure that you have header guards in your header files; otherwise, you might encounter `error: redefinition of 'class InclinoMeasure'` after including `Inclino.h` in `InclinoMeasure.cpp`.

Comment: All seems ok if I include the 2 files + the 2 forward declaration for each class file. The program works as expecteed but is it a good code ? (and yes I have header guards). Thanks again for your help.